# How to add a user to a guild automatically?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm aware of the `Guild.leave()` method in Discord.js, but is there any way to add a *user* to a guild automatically? I know so-called "selfbots" are against Discord's Terms of Service, but I've been searching for 5 days now and can't find anything...

Comment: English only on this site please.

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is an old question, but for those like myself that has been confused about this:

1. You need to integrate an OAuth for discord first, note that this needs to have `guilds.join` scope. Just follow [this docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#authorization-code-grant)
2. You need to create a bot and add it on your guild. You can create a bot on your [Application page](https://discord.com/developers/applications#top) Follow this [Authorization guide](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#bot-authorization-flow-url-example) to know how to authorize your bot.
3. Once the bot is created, you can get the `token` on the `Bot` Tab in your [Bot Application page](https://discord.com/developers/applications#top). Keep that token somewhere.
4. To auto join a user, you need to call this [API endpoint](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member).

   - Headers will look like:

     - ```
       {
           ['Content-Type']: 'application/json',
           Authorization: 'Bot <bot token from step 3>'
       }
       ```
   - Body should be:

     - ```
       {
            access_token: '<access token of user you want to add. (see: step 1)>',
            // other body data
       }
       ```
   - My code is in PHP (the question is nodejs) and it still depends on the nodejs library that you're using (axios, node.fetch, nock, etc.) but to give you an idea on what it looks like:

     - ```
       $request = (new Client())->patch(
           'https://discord.com/api/v8/guilds/' . $guildId . '/members/' . $discordUserID, 
           [
               'headers' => [
                   'Authorization' => 'Bot ' . $token,
                   'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
               ],
               'json' => [
                   'roles' => $userRoles
               ]
           ]
       );
       ```

       `$userRoles` is an array of Guild Role Id where you can get via this [API endpoint](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild-roles). This is optional, only if you want to give the user a role.

Comment: plz add code example for step 4

Comment: @padavan I've added one, although its on PHP, I did not converted it to node as I don't have much experience with nodejs. its only to give you an idea on what it looks like.

Answer (score 3):

In order to gain permission to add a Discord user to a server, your client must be granted an OAuth2 access token with the `guilds.join` scope. Click [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2) for the official Discord documentation on the OAuth2 flow and examples.

In Discord.js, adding a user to a server is possible, but only after following the OAuth2 process as described in the linked documentation. See [`Guild#addMember()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Guild?scrollTo=addMember) to add a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/User) to a [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Guild) with an access token.

Comment: But how is this to use? I know its against the Discord terms but HOW im searching 5 days...

Comment: @Nadelvorhang If you have some pressing need to know, open discord in browser, open your browser's developer tools, accept an invite and inspect the request that gets made when you do so. There you can see the necessary headers and request body. Just be aware that selfbots scraping invites and joining servers automatically is about **the biggest reason** discord separated out the bot API and banned selfbots. They have ways of detecting such automated requests and you are very likely to have your IP banned if you go about such attempts.

Comment: @Klaycon I know it bannable / Against the Discord Terms but i never saw a code for this! I want to see something like
(client.join or client.accept_invite). I want a working Code or im not happy lol

Comment: @Nadelvorhang There is no method in any API wrapper (i.e. Discord.js) for a bot to join a server, because bots have no way through the Discord API to do so without an OAuth2 authorization link.

Comment: @slothiful Yes i know but the question was if i use an normal Account Token

Comment: @Nadelvorhang Do not attempt to do so. Theoretically, you would POST to the invite endpoint as shown in my answer. As Klaycon said, investigate the requests made by the Discord client and formulate your own request out of it with an HTTP client. See [here](https://nodejs.dev/making-http-requests-with-nodejs) for more about HTTP requests in Node.js.

Comment: @slothiful Yes i know but i need a WORKING finished code otherwise im not Happy lol

Comment: @Nadelvorhang StackOverflow is not a code writing service. That being said, we'd love to lead you to your end goal through answers to *questions*.

Comment: @Nadelvorhang There *is no working code* using something like discord.js to do this. Discord.js *does not support this* with any kind of token. You need to use any generic request library to make the request completely manually (this can be done in your discord.js project, but it won't use discord.js at all).

Comment: @Nadelvorhang I've made an edit to include the real answer to your question. My apologies for the previous misleading conversation; there's a way to accomplish your goal incorporated into the API.