# discord.py Joining a server (Rewrite)

Tags: discord.py

I am making a **Discord SelfBot** just to learn/understand more of discord.py, **before I start, I do not intend on using this on servers! It is for fun and to learn.**

How can I make it so when you run the bot, it makes you join a certain discord server?
I cannot find anything on the internet etc so I do not know really what to do.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59548815/how-to-add-a-user-to-a-guild-automatically

Comment: that is discord.js though, im on about discord.py

Answer (score 2):

The simple fact of connecting to the API using a user token outside the context of discord's official client is expressly forbidden in the ToS. Also, you say you don't want to use it on "servers" yet your question is how to join a server...

Comment: Because I am trying to learn how it works and I was curious how people do it, also it would only be used on my servers with only me

Comment: Even if you used it in your servers only you could be banned for that, also you can learn with normal bots, it's pretty much the same code

Comment: your not likely to be banned unless you do to many api request stuff or if you get reported

Comment: Well alright, for the sake of "fun and learning". There is no method in the discord.py library to accept an invite. You'd need to make a custom request using the token in an authoriation header, then the url would be something like https://discordapp.com/api/v6/invites/{invite_code}. Im not sure if that endpoint is still valid though, its probably v7 or v8 now.

Keep in mind discord staff can get you spotted even if you dont do crazy stuff. Dont use selfbots.